# Connect to Password Protected Zoom Calls with Twilio Voice

Tags: node.js, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-node

Earlier I used to connect to Zoom calls as follows:

```js
this.twilioClient.calls.create({
    record: true,
    recordingStatusCallback: process.env.POST_RECORDING_WEBHOOK,
    url: process.env.TWILIO_HELLO_TWIML,
    recordingStatusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
    from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
    statusCallback: process.env.TWILIO_STATUS_WEBHOOK,
    statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
    to: phoneNumber,
    sendDigits: 'www' + <call_sid>+ #ww#',
});
```

However, now, if a call also has a meeting password as well, for example:

Meeting ID: 9_digit_number

Password: Some_alphanumeric_string

How should I modify my function for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

According to [the Zoom documentation](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362663-Joining-a-meeting-by-phone?mobile_site=true#h_36d1152f-01cf-43cf-a565-bc4cbb4d23e3):

> If the meeting requires a password, a phone-specific numeric password will be generated. You can find this password in the invitation listed below the dial-in numbers and meeting ID.

So you can use your code, you just need to find the phone-specific password.